# Android inflate linear layout with data from database

Tags: android-layout, android-listview, android-linearlayout

Hi I'm building an android app. I'm fetching some data from my database and inflating it in a layout. Currently I'm displaying the data in a Listview. But Is there any other way than showing data in a Listview? I mean like displaying the data in a linear layout just like the way how Listview displays?

I don't want to use a Listview because my contents are placed in a ScrollView and using a ListView inside ScrollView doesn't display the height of the Listview elements completely.

Please have a look at the image

[image: Picture for representation]

I want my entire layout to scroll. To be more simple I want a full window scrolling just like we have in facebook android app in comments section. Like a image at top and comments at bottom and the whole window scrolls but commenting edittext and button remain fixed.

Any help??

Sorry if my question was too long.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Hi Syed Sehu Mujammil A,

You can utilize the [LinearListViewlibrary](https://github.com/frankiesardo/LinearListView) to achieve your goal. This library allows you to create a ListAdapter that binds to a LinearLayout. You can then put this "ListView" (it is not really a ListView under the hood) within a ScrollView. Then your entire layout could scroll how you want it to.

For example, you could setup your view like this:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            
            <!-- Your Title and other stuff in the green section here -->
        </LinearLayout>

        <com.linearlistview.LinearListView
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/main_linear_list_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:showDividers="none|middle|beginning|end"
            android:divider="#488888"
            android:dividerPadding="2dp"
            app:dividerThickness="2dp"
            />


    </ScrollView>
```

You can then treat the LinearListView with a BaseAdapter or ListAdapter like a normal ListView (make sure you optimize your getView() method). The thing to be careful here though is that this library utilizes a linearlayout and loading a lot of elements may lock up the UI thread (unlike a ListView which will smartly load objects in and out). It is possible to smartly handle your getView() and notifyDatasetChange() methods to better optimize the initial loading (IE: things like AsyncTasks with ExecutorThreadPools to help load the data).

I hope that helps!

-Evan